# Error: Could not run command from prerun_command: Execution of '/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre' returned 1:

Tags: linux, puppet

Hello when I go to apply my site.pp to a client I get the above error, here it is again:

```
      Error: Could not run command from prerun_command: Execution of '/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre' returned 1:
```

My Puppet.conf on my puppet master:

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
templatedir=$confdir/templates
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post
certname=darmstadtium.shadowk.at
dns_alt_names=darmstadtium.shadowk.at
manifest=/etc/puppet/manifests/

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY



puppet.conf on agent: 
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
templatedir=$confdir/templates
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post
server=darmstadtium.shadowk.at

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
```

Comment: What's puppet version? read this first [prerun_command don't stop puppet on error](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/7127)

Comment: Version 3.4.1 on the master and client

Comment: Put a wrapper script around etckeeper. Make it enable verbose mode and collect the output somewhere. Use this as the prerun command to find out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Met the same error with puppet 4.8.2 fresh install (debian stretch). Seems etckeeper_command_pre and etckeeper_command_post were not copied into /etc/puppet/ where puppet.conf says they should be.

I found them in /usr/share/doc/puppet/examples/etckeeper-integration/ (using locate), copied then into /etc/puppet and did a chmod +x on them.

puppet agent -t ran like a charm after this.